# Any differences between ( var > x) and ( x < var)?

Tags: c++, coding-style

I have seen embedded programming use conditions in reverse order like literal on the left side instead of right in conditional checks.

```
( var > 0) and ( 0 < var)
```

Is there a reason for this ? or its just a one of coding style ?

Thanks

EDIT: Thanks everyone for answering and clearing my doubt.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't change the semantical meaning (if `<` and `>` are symetrically implemented). I read (some decades ago) about "defensive" programming which helps to uncover typos and programming errors more easily. In that sense, the latter is a bit more defensive. (Unfortunately, I forgot the actual reason why.)

Comment: Coding style (in a sane world, operator< and operator> could be implemented differently). But from an understanding point of view the first is preferable.

Comment: It makes more sense for `=` vs. `==`. Imagine, you confused both in a condition: `var = 0` instead of `var == 0` is syntactically correct. `0 = var` instead of `0 == var` makes a compiler error. (non-lvalue on left side of `=`)

Comment: It would be interesting to see what the respective underlying assembly/machine code would be; perhaps it would be the same.

Comment: That is used as "defensive programming". In fact you can compare fine (var == 0) or do it wrong (var = 0). In second case you are asigning var with value zero, and that is hard to debug. If you replace by (0 = var), that generates a compiling error, and that is easier to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are equivalent. The only difference could be if `operator<`/`>` is overloaded, and these overloads have difference meaning (discouraged, though).

I've seen people doing this for the equality operator, to avoid using assigment mistakely. So instead of this:

```
if (a==0) ...
```

Mistakenly this is written:

```
if (a=0) ... // compiles, and not what we wanted, a assigned to zero, and "if" never taken
```

If we have used reversed comparison instead:

```
if (0==a) ...
```

Then the wrong version doesn't compile:

```
if (0=a) ... // doesn't compile
```

But this is not too important today, as most compilers will [warn](https://godbolt.org/z/M97SOC) you for `if (a=0)`.

As Max Langhof notes, this reversed condition is called [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) due to the order being different from the normal English one.

Comment: This `0 == a` form is also called [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) due to the order being different from the normal English one.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: nice info, I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is just personal taste. Well, some argue that in comparisons for equality the literal should alwas be on the left side to get a compiler error for unintended assignments:

intended:

```
if(x == 42) // ...
```

typo:

```
if(x = 42) // ... most likely a warning
```

compiler error:

```
if(42 = x) // ...
```